# Catch and transform error raised inside py.allow_threads closure?

Tags: rust, error-handling, closures, pyo3

I have a PyO3 function like this:

```
#[pyfunction]
fn update_index(py: Python, dir_root_path_str: String, index_name: String, n_docx_docs: usize) 
    -> PyResult<(usize, usize)> {
    py.allow_threads(move || {
        ...
        let (docx_hit_objs_for_processing, docx_hit_objs_for_deletion) = match op_handler.analyse_index_correspondence() {
            Ok((docx_hit_objs_for_processing, docx_hit_objs_for_deletion)) => (docx_hit_objs_for_processing, docx_hit_objs_for_deletion),
            Err(e) => {return Err(PyErr::new::<PyTypeError, _>(e.to_string()))}
        };
        ...
```

Signature of the above method:

```
fn analyse_index_correspondence(&self) ->
    Result<(Vec<DocxHitObject>, Vec<DocxHitObject>), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
```

Anyone reasonably familiar with PyO3 will understand the problem: the error has to be "wrapped" or "transformed" to be able to pass as an error acceptable to `PyResult` (which would then result in an exception in the Python code).

The problem is that there are several commands in this closure and each is having to do this wrapping for the error. So I was wondering whether there's a way of doing this wrapping outside the closure, which would mean I could just use `?`. I have tried things like this:

```
    py.allow_threads(move || {
        ...
        let (docx_hit_objs_for_processing, docx_hit_objs_for_deletion) 
            = op_handler.analyse_index_correspondence()?;
        ...
        Ok((a, b))
    }) match {
        Ok(tuple) => Ok(tuple),
        Err(e) => {Err(PyErr::new::<PyTypeError, _>(e.to_string()))}
    }
}
```

This gives compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `pyo3::PyErr`
  --> src\lib.rs:45:109
   |
45 |         let (docx_hit_objs_for_processing, docx_hit_objs_for_deletion) = op_handler.analyse_index_correspondence()?;
   |                                                                                                                   ^ the trait `From<Box<dyn StdError>>` is not implemented for `pyo3::PyErr`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&CancelledError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&IncompleteReadError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&InvalidStateError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&LimitOverrunError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&PanicException>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&PyArithmeticError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&PyAssertionError>>
             <pyo3::PyErr as From<&PyAttributeError>>
           and 87 others
   = note: required for `Result<_, pyo3::PyErr>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, Box<dyn StdError>>>`
```

The docs for `allow_threads` is [here](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/marker/struct.Python.html#method.allow_threads). Its return type is said to be `Ungil`, which makes me worried. Any way to achieve this?

Obviously a simple solution is to have a single command in this function, and to do all the multiple commands in another called function, which returns `Result<((usize, usize)), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` and then this `Ok`/`Err` block handles things here as shown. But I'm just wondering whether it is possible to catch things outside this closure here, in this function.

**Edit: cafce's suggestion**
I tried doing this:

```
py.allow_threads(move || -> Result<(usize, usize), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    ...
```

This gives the following compiler errors:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn StdError` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\lib.rs:27:5
    |
27  |     py.allow_threads(move || -> Result<(usize, usize), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn StdError` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn StdError`
    = note: required for `Unique<dyn StdError>` to implement `Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn Error>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Result<(usize, usize), Box<dyn Error>>`
    = note: required for `Result<(usize, usize), Box<dyn StdError>>` to implement `Ungil`
note: required by a bound in `pyo3::Python::<'py>::allow_threads`
   --> D:\apps\rust\rust_1.70.0\.cargo\git\checkouts\pyo3-a22e69bc62b9f0fd\8dc3d2b\src\marker.rs:531:12
    |
531 |         T: Ungil,
    |            ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Python::<'py>::allow_threads`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\lib.rs:27:2
   |
24 |       -> PyResult<(usize, usize)> {
   |          ------------------------ expected `Result<(usize, usize), PyErr>` because of return type
```

I understand the second error. But regarding the first I think I'm in deep waters here. Think I'll just have to call a second "pure Rust" function as I suggested above.

Comment: Don't you just have to put the call inside of match as in `match py.allow_threads(...) { ... }`?

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that, with the `Ok`/`Err` block 1) after the closing "}" and 2) after the closing ")". Neither compiles.

Comment: Why after the `}`? the arms go inside of `{}` so `match py.allow_threads(...) { Ok(tup) => tup, Err(e) => {...}}`.

Comment: Yes, as I say I tried that as well. I get "`?` couldn't convert the error to `pyo3::PyErr`" and "^ the trait `From<Box<dyn StdError>>` is not implemented for `pyo3::PyErr`"

Comment: Also if something doesn't compile *add the compiler error to the question*.

Comment: That error isn'trelated to anything in your [mre].

Comment: I haven't given an MRE. But I don't understand your comment there. The code at the top works fine. The "wrapped" `PyErr` is thrown outside the closure and this compiles OK. I just want to see if there's a way to catch a `Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` **outside** the closure.

Comment: Ah  I think I understand now, yes you should be able to by just defining the return type of the closure `move || -> Result<..., Box<dyn Error>>`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and will edit question.

Comment: Is it as simple as adding `Send` to the trait object? I.e. `Box<dyn Error + Send>` (maybe `Sync` in addition).

Comment: Thanks again. Tried that (both ideas): many compiler errors, including "error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn StdError` cannot be known at compilation time".